# Ruby 1.9.3 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, actionview

I was using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.11 for more than year and I developed my application using it, when I upgraded my ruby version to 1.9.3 these issue raised

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT on my application.js file
```

I tried many solutions but all fails any body can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.8, strings weren't encoded. In 1.9.3, you need to say what character set encoding your string is using. The default is ASCII, which is a problem, as you can't add differently encoded strings together.

For more information, look here:

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

To fix it, make sure your strings and files are all using UTF 8 (or whatever you want) encoding, and your database has the right types.

Comment: I have translation for arabic ,,so how can I convert my all files to be UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: the problem mainly appears on application.js file

Comment: Add # encoding: utf-8 to the top of your application.js file to tell it to use that encoding.

Comment: I added it but application js not loaded